# Deploying Web App in a Server

Tags: web-hosting, traffic-management

I would like to Deploy a Web app which provides Web Services and I want some more traffic to get. So I'm doubting to purchase web host. Because most of the Unlimited web hosting packages are very very expensive. I cannot determine what are the specification that I should have to deploy this web site if I'm not going to choose unlimited package?(Eg:How much traffic should have to choose,hosting space...etc)

Comment: And waht do you expect from us? We know even less about your application than you - because we dont even know the application. It all depends, and you determined that providing information is a useless task for you. Voted to close.

Comment: My App totally works for Online transaction(buying and selling)and with a Social platform(just like FaceBook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an affordable web host for now, because it seems that you are not sure on how much traffic you will get.  It makes no sense in getting an unlimited account, as there is a chance that nobody will use your service, and if thats the case, you'll be out a large amount of money.  As traffic increases, you can scale up your hosting, or get multiple hosting packages to distribute the load